# MongoDB regex for numbers

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

There is a regex which checks correctly if a string is found in the values:

```
{ name: { $regex: req.query.name, $options: 'i' } },
```

The problem is if the "name" isn't a string but a number. Is there a way to change it and make it check for number values too? Without losing the string checking functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cast them to `string` by `$toString`, this is Mongo way (since Mongo 4.2+, you can use the `$regexMatch|$regexFind|$regexFindAll`):

```js
{
    "$expr": {
        "$regexMatch": {
           "input": {"$toString": "$name"}, 
           "regex": req.query.name 
        }
    }
}
```